# Ruby on Rails : image tag with variables from a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I am looking for the corresponding tag of the following html code:

```
<img src="/assets/folder1/<%= @user.fullname %>.jpg" style='height:100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' alt="user" />
```

As you can see the part of the link to the picture is define by the varaiable user.fullname. The html works well but I am looking for the equivalent in Ruby.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3):

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

```
image_tag("/assets/folder1/#{ @user.fullname }.jpg", class: 'image')
```

CSS

```
img.image {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `image_tag`?

Comment: Whoops, sorry .