# How do I use image_tag in <img class="rounded-circle">

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the code below to display a user avatar picture.  This picture can be accessed by using `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar) %>`

I'm unsure of how to replace the `src=` in the code below because previous attempts to replace it ended in failure.

```
<img class="rounded-circle" width="45" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">
```

Previously I use to used `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar,  style: 'width:50%') %>`
to show images, but I prefer the styling of the `<img class>` more.  If anybody can help we out with this on point me into the direction of some documention on this I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: hopefully this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182006/ruby-on-rails-image-tag-with-variables-from-a-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails : image tag with variables from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182006/ruby-on-rails-image-tag-with-variables-from-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use image_tag like this

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url, class: "rounded-circle" ,alt: ""%>
    <style type="text/css">
    .rounded-circle{
    width: 45px;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class="rounded-circle" width="45" <%=image_tag("No_image.jpg")%>
```

This ended up working for me.  Seems like when I was trying to do it at first I was using the `<%` instead of `<%=` user error is the worst!  Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```ruby
<%= image_tag(@user.avatar,  class: 'rounded-circle') %>
```